# With $when vs without $when for ajaxRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

May I know what is the difference for the script below (With $when vs without $when for ajaxRequest )

```
$.when(ajaxRequest("GET", "Api/Filter/Country", null, true)).done(function (data) {
    return data;
});
```

And below

```
ajaxRequest("GET", "Api/Filter/Country", null, true).done(function (data) {
        return data;
    });
```

Main Function

```
ajaxRequest: function (type, url, data) {
            var options = {
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                cache: false,
                type: type,
                data: data ? ko.toJSON(data) : null
            };

            var antiForgeryToken = $("[name='__RequestVerificationToken']")[0].value;
            if (antiForgeryToken) {
                options.headers = {
                    'RequestVerificationToken': antiForgeryToken
                }
            }
            return $.ajax(url, options);
        }
```

Comment: There's no logical difference, though the first example is redundant as `ajaxRequest` is already returning a jqXHR object so the use of `$.when()` is not needed at all

Comment: You typically would only use `$.when()` if you have more than one request being made and want code to run when all are complete